# How do I add Parent and child nodes to a tree view on checking a checkbox

Tags: wpf

if check box is checked, tree view should be created and populated.
On un checking the checkbox,it it should be hidden

Comment: @Muds  following mvvm..

Answer (score 1):

If you follow MVVM

then you can have a style set on Checkbox ischecked to control visibility of your tree or you can set a visibility converter on binding of checkbox.

then you should bind your checkbox to a viewmodel property, when that value is set, you should populate your itemsList that is bound to your tree control

let me know if you do not understand any part !